# Updating a DIV on Submit without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need refresh `<myDiv>` on my webpage when the Submit button is clicked.

I created an example of what I need. I want to display the user input text inside `<myDiv>` when the Submit button is clicked. Currently it's not showing anything. How can I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/NathaliaZeed/8dn5j/2/

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Where is the url parameter for your ajax call?

Comment: You need to write a handler to receive the POST (and send back a response if needs be). You will need to use a server-side language like PHP, C# etc to do this.

Comment: You have written php code in **js** fiddle.

Comment: @Murali: I've removed it on purpose because the php is right there. `if( isset($_POST['val1']) ){`

Comment: @Vikas: Can't php be in the HTML section (jsFiddle)?

Comment: `$('#btn').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $("#myDiv").html($('#val1').val()); ..ajax stuff..});`

Comment: @user3687622 No, a php code goes into *.php file and html goes into *.html file, while html code can be included inside php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use complete: not done:, then, assign your val1 variable to myDiv.
Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8dn5j/14/

See below:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) {   
    var val1 = $('#val1').val();    
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',                
        data: {'val1':val1},                    
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            $("#myDiv").html(val1);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example is good, except you forget to load the jQuery library.
If you make sure you include jQuery, the javascript code should work.

Also, your example should run on a PHP server. JSfiddle does not interpret PHP code, so that is also why the example does not work.
If you don't have a PHP server, Google for WAMP for Windows or MAMP for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure why you need php and ajax if there is only need to update the div on button click and not doing any server side processing for the need you described in question this code will work

```
<div class="myDiv" id="myDiv"></div>

<div class="sear">
     <form action="" method="post">
     Search Word:    <br />     
         <input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" /><br />
         <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" />
        </form>
      </div>
```

Js

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) {   
        var val1 = $('#val1').val();    
            $("#myDiv").html(val1);
             $("#myDiv").toggle("slow");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you don't need to use the form-tag..

I would do it this way:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e) {   
var val1 = $('#val1').val();    

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',                
            data: {val1:val1},                    
        success: function(data) { 
                $("#myDiv").text(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it doesn't do anything with Ajax request.

```
 $('#btn').click(function(e) {  e.preventDefault();

 $("#myDiv").html($('#val1').val());   

 //..ajax stuff..

 });
```